# MPU 6050 Digital Motion Processor Gyro Units

Tags: accelerometer, motion, gyroscope

I'm running into an odd issue with a motion control processor (MPU 6050 / 9150) that is returning raw gyroscope values as specified between the -/+ 32768 which in the way this gyro is configured corresponds to -/+ 2000 deg / sec. This makes total sense as this goes along with the specified documentation.

However, when I process data from the digital motion processor (6 axis sensor fusion) I get a maximum of 1429. I don't think that there's an error reading the data from the MPU buffer as the other measurements look good (reading from the same FIFO buffer). I assume this is likely some units issue that has to do with the 6 axis sensor fusion, and also likely involving radians

Wondering if any of you bright people with your light bulb brains have some insight here?

Comment: 2000 deg/sec is pretty fast, it means 5.5 rounds per second or 333rpm. Have you spin it at that speed?

Comment: Yea my application is a frisbee so its pretty easy to max out. 300rpm is on the lower end of the range. (300-1000)

Comment: Have you tried without fusion algorithm, to record only gyro rate? Likely the fusion algorithm, which is unknown and kept secure, is used for mobile devices, posture sensors,..etc everything to wear on humans or animals, perhaps the freesbee is an overkill for the algo.

Comment: Your MPU gyros saturating at 1429 even if You spin at maximum speed or it is one maximum reading You were read (and most of readings were below 1429)? I suspect hardware problem with capacitor connected to charge pump (pin 20).

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yea I've been able to read the 'raw' gyro values and they come out as expected.

Comment: @lustful-rat I don't think its hardware i've tried with a few different configurations (MPU 6050, MPU 9150) and each time it gives good values for everything but it seems they gyro is scaled oddly.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that my dmp packet structure is off from the specification.

The DMP returns a 48byte packet, and the accelerometer and gyroscope values coming out are 32 bit integers. When handled improperly this gives scaled and wrong data.

```
    /* ================================================================================================ *
 | Default MotionApps v4.1 48-byte FIFO packet structure:                                           |
 |                                                                                                  |
 | [QUAT W][      ][QUAT X][      ][QUAT Y][      ][QUAT Z][      ][GYRO X][      ][GYRO Y][      ] |
 |   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  |
 |                                                                                                  |
 | [GYRO Z][      ][MAG X ][MAG Y ][MAG Z ][ACC X ][      ][ACC Y ][      ][ACC Z ][      ][      ] |
 |  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  |
 * ================================================================================================ */
```

Comment: Perhaps you have trouble with endianess. If you look for ex. quaternion W comes in  0, 1, 2, 3 byte that's 32-bit, but possibly you read them swaped, for ex. the output is big endian and you read as little endian.